# C++ input not being read

Tags: c++, input, cin

I just started with c++ (coming from java) and I'm trying to do some basic exercises. The idea is to ask for any input other than 5, if the user inputs 5, display a message, and if the user inputs anything other than 5 ten times, display another message. Here's the code:

```
void notFive () {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10) {
        int input = 0;
        cout << "Enter any number other than 5." << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 5)
            break;
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 10)
        cout<<"You are more patient than I am, you win.";
    else
        cout << "You weren't supposed to enter 5!";
}   
}
```

My problem is that all this code does is print out "Enter any number other than 5." 10 times, then  say "You are more patient that I am, you win." any ideas what is wrong?

if you guys want all my code (to make sure I'm not just being an idiot) here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Hello {

public:
    void notFive () {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 10) {
        int input = 0;
        cout << "Enter any number other than 5." << endl;
        if ( ! (cin >> input) ) {
            cout << "std::cin is in a bad state!  Aborting!" << endl;
            return;
}
        if (input == 5)
            break;
        count++;
        }
        if (count == 10)
            cout<<"You are more patient than I am, you win.";
        else
            cout << "You weren't supposed to enter 5!";
    }   
}hello;

int main() {
    Hello h;
    h.notFive();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you do any other input before this? If `cin` is in a bad state, it will not attempt to perform any more input.

Comment: At a guess, the standard input is not connected to an interactive terminal equivalent.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line failed?

Comment: Using Sublime Text 2 with MinGW on Windows.

Comment: and no previous input.

Comment: 1) Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). 2) You never check to see if the input succeeded. Try `if(cin >> input) { ..check for 5..} else { std::cout << "Error\n"; return; }`

Comment: Are you specifying `-mwindows` to the compiler?  You shouldn't be - that's for GUI programs with no console.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly for me (in Visual Studio 2012) when I change `notFive` to `main`. Your problem must lie outside this code (possibly because `cin` is in a broken state, as others have suggested).

Comment: I can say the same thing for Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
cin >> input
```

To this:

```
if ( ! (cin >> input) ) {
    cout << "std::cin is in a bad state!  Aborting!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

The behavior you describe is what would happen if *Something Bad* happened to `cin` *before* this code was run.

**Edit:**

Add this same code to earlier uses of `cin` to find out where it's entering a bad state.

An example of this happening would be if the code tried to read an `int`, and the user typed a letter of the alphabet.

You can also call `cin.clear();` to restore the working state of `cin`.

Comment: this is the only time I ever use cin in the program

Comment: @abaratham as others have noted, there is no bug in the code you've posted.  The problem is likely in the environment its being run in.

Comment: any idea how to fix it? everything worked with eclipse but i just recently switched to using Sublime Text

Comment: @abaratham it sounds like you have a completely new question now.  I suggest that you post it.  You'll get more eyes on it that way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments:

1. `fflush(stdin)` is not valid.  The `stdin` cannot be flushed.  Also,
   this may not be the same input as `cin`.
2. You need to check for `cin.fail` after `cin >> input`.  If I enter a
   letter, your input statement will fail.

Comment: Hmm. There is no mention of `fflush(stdin)` anywhere outside your answer.

Comment: i edited fflush(stdin) out, it was just something my teacher was trying to do to fix this.